# The first 10 shortest paths in a graph - Igraph 0.6 - Python 2.7

Tags: python, graph, path, shortest-path, igraph

I was wondering about this ever since I've started to successfully implement Igraph into my coding: Can you retrieve with **get_all_shortest_paths** as many shortest paths as you like. Let's say first 10.

I've understood so far that retrieving ALL shortest paths in a undirected graph is non-sense since in most cases you have infinite amount of them.

But can I **simply retrieve first 10 shortest paths?**

I've tried to achieve this with an undirected g = Graph() :

```
list = []
list.append(g.get_all_shortest_paths(index1,index2, "distance")[0])   # shortest path
list.append(g.get_all_shortest_paths(index1,index2, "distance")[1])   # second shortest path
list.append(g.get_all_shortest_paths(index1,index2, "distance")[2])   # third shortest path
list.append(g.get_all_shortest_paths(index1,index2, "distance")[3])   # forth shortest path
list.append(g.get_all_shortest_paths(index1,index2, "distance")[4])   # fifth shortest path
list.append(g.get_all_shortest_paths(index1,index2, "distance")[5])   # sixth shortest path
list.append(g.get_all_shortest_paths(index1,index2, "distance")[6])   # seventh shortest path
list.append(g.get_all_shortest_paths(index1,index2, "distance")[7])   # eigth shortest path
list.append(g.get_all_shortest_paths(index1,index2, "distance")[8])   # ninth shortest path
list.append(g.get_all_shortest_paths(index1,index2, "distance")[9])   # tenth shortest path

#"distance" is from g.es["distance"]
```

It would alway give me error that **list index is out of range**. 
Actually I can't even get `list.append(g.get_all_shortest_paths(index1,index2, "distance")[1])`, though I know there are more then 10 paths there.

There is nothing special about the graph. thousands of vertexes, all connected somehow, I mean various vertex degrees.

Finally I would like to have a wx.spin or wx.ComboBox to choose between the paths (i.e. the shortest path which is a national highway in real life has ice on it during winter so I would like to take the second shortest road between City1 and City2... then oh no.. that has kangoroos jumping all over it so I take the third, or better forth path because there I know a McDonalds and I really like to eat junk food bla bla)

I know shortest != short, though I need something like: if shortest no good then ignore that, go to second and so on.
I've searched Google but it is not clear for me how can I do this.

Thank you in advance!

Edit: I might mention that `list.append(g.get_all_shortest_paths(index1,index2, "distance")[1])` of course is working when there are exactly 2 shortest paths with naturally the exact same distances.

**Important Update:**

Since I've ingloriously misunderstood `g.get_all_shortest_paths` this part will change in my code to `g.get_shortest_paths(index1, index2, weights=distance, mode=ALL, output="vpath")` and I also mention that the graph is weighted, but that bit is obvious anyway:

```
list = []
g.es["weight"] = distance
list.append(g.get_shortest_paths(index1, index2, weights=distance, mode=ALL, output="vpath")[0])   # shortest path
list.append(g.get_shortest_paths(index1, index2, weights=distance, mode=ALL, output="vpath")[1])   # second shortest path
list.append(g.get_shortest_paths(index1, index2, weights=distance, mode=ALL, output="vpath")[2])   # third shortest path
list.append(g.get_shortest_paths(index1, index2, weights=distance, mode=ALL, output="vpath")[3])   # forth shortest path
list.append(g.get_shortest_paths(index1, index2, weights=distance, mode=ALL, output="vpath")[4])   # fifth shortest path
list.append(g.get_shortest_paths(index1, index2, weights=distance, mode=ALL, output="vpath")[5])   # sixth shortest path
list.append(g.get_shortest_paths(index1, index2, weights=distance, mode=ALL, output="vpath")[6])   # seventh shortest path
list.append(g.get_shortest_paths(index1, index2, weights=distance, mode=ALL, output="vpath")[7])   # eigth shortest path
list.append(g.get_shortest_paths(index1, index2, weights=distance, mode=ALL, output="vpath")[8])   # ninth shortest path
list.append(g.get_shortest_paths(index1, index2, weights=distance, mode=ALL, output="vpath")[9])   # tenth shortest path

#"distance" is a list containing the weights
# graph is TRUE-ly weighted now
```

**How to get the first 10 or all short paths between two vertex's?**

This question is still looking for its answer to be accepted. Thank you.

*(P.S. I've kept the wrong approach in the first part of the question since might be other enormous idiobooms out there like me who try the same thing)*

Comment: Two things that you might be missing: 1. Even though the number of *paths* in a cyclic graph in general might be infinite, the number of *shortest* paths between any two nodes is finite, unless you have edges with zero weights, loops with negative total weight, or any other evilness like that. 2. `get_all_shortest_paths` does not support edge weights, so the third argument is not the name of the attribute that holds the distances.

Comment: 3. What you plan to do is gonna be terribly inefficient because you will be calculating all the shortest paths 10 times between the same node pair. Just calculate all the shortest paths once and slice the list: `paths = g.get_all_shortest_paths(index1, index2)[:10]`.

Comment: Ah, I get it. I will have it a go. The third argument seemed to work correctly. Is that a missbelief? Serious question because I have a series of attributes such es "roadcode", "difficulty" etc. I used `g.get_all_shortest_paths(index1, index2,"difficulty")` and it seems to be such as a weight with the value given by "difficulty". I say it because it worked so far. I don't understand.

Comment: The third argument will not work correctly. The function accepts any string there, but the only values that make sense are `in`, `out` and `all`; they determine the direction in which directed edges are allowed to be traversed.

Comment: +1 for all your very useful comments Tamás. Thank you again. I'm shocked though, because I've spent much time believing that the third argument is working as I wished in my mind. I need to change now everything there. Already looking up [is_weighted()](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc-0.6.5/python/igraph.Graph-class.html#is_weighted) . Could you propose some further documentation to do the weighted graph from that third attribute and to do what this entire question is about? Just links are enough if you have them on your mind. I don't wan't to hold you up from developing great libraries :)

Comment: I've updated the question with the correct alternative to get_all_shortest_paths. My bad. Slicing is not working this way. Other options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I'm still unsure what you mean by the "first 10 shortest paths", but here is what I *think* you might want to achieve. You have a graph where the edges are labeled by the actual (say, Euclidean) distance of the two endpoints. You are given two points, and you wish to find a few alternate paths between them while trying to keep these paths as short as possible. Note that since your graph is weighted, it is very unlikely that you will have many *shortest* paths between two points - in order for all of the paths to be the *shortest*, they must have *exactly* the same total weight. If your weights measure actual distances "as the crow flies", it is very unlikely that such a co-occurrence ever happens - the ten paths you would be looking for would have slightly different lengths. So, `get_all_shortest_paths` is not useful to you, not only because it does not use weights, but also because even if it did, you are unlikely find multiple paths between two points that have exactly the same length.

An alternative is `get_shortest_paths`, which can consider weights, but it will return only *one* path between a pair of vertices. (The reason why it is called `get_shortest_paths` is because it returns *multiple* paths if you specify multiple target vertices - more precisely, it gives you one path for each target vertex). So, you cannot use `get_shortest_paths` to obtain the ten paths you are looking for.

After some googling, I have found an [implementation of the k-shortest-paths algorithm](https://code.google.com/p/k-shortest-paths/) that might be useful for you. It is not part of `igraph`, but you can save your graph from `igraph`, call out to the compiled executable of the k-shortest-paths algorithm using `os.system` or the `subprocess` module in Python and then parse the result somehow.

Comment: I see. You worked alot on this I think. Thank you. I also googled meanwhile and found this [All possible paths between one node to another...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971876/all-possible-paths-from-one-node-to-another-in-a-directed-tree-igraph) . I see you also commented here on a solution. I think I should try to retrieve all paths like there. Let's not focus on shortest path, let's get all of them somehow and later sum the weights. I couldn't get that example to work for me. It would be great if it would be possible to get all paths and work with them only after that.

Comment: If I would have all paths (i.e. vertex ID's on that path like above example) then I could just sum the attributes of edges connecting them and that would give me endless opportunities in my view. I'm sorry that I didn't express my self clearly. Is this approach possible? Again thank you Tamás. Really.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971876/all-possible-paths-from-one-node-to-another-in-a-directed-tree-igraph this is I think close to the answer but unable to implement it. It's not working for me.

Comment: This is not gonna work for you; the assumption behind that code is that your graph is directed and acyclic - in other words, it does not contain cycles. Your graph does, so that algorithm would fall in an infinite loop. The *real* solution would be to code a k-shortest-path algorithm in Python. The second best solution is to try an external k-shortest-paths implementation like the one I linked above.

Comment: The third best solution is to list all simple paths (i.e. those that do not contain the same node twice) between your source and target points, and take the ten shortest; this can be done with the all_simple_paths routine in NetworkX; see http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html. The problem with this approach is that the number of such paths can be huge unless your graph is very small.

Comment: Yepp, you are right. I've managed to implement that code from the link with your comment at it and it is indeed infinite. I will try out your suggestion in order of best ideas and will try to limit the work until it finds the first 10 paths where the first is the shortest, second the second shortest path and so on until 10-15, depeding on runtime. I think your answer is more than acceptable. You have my eternal respect!

Comment: Third solution, all_simple_paths is out of question. It's so slow that's like infinite. For very short paths with no alternative paths it's indeed okey but who wants that? I was wondering but now I understand why this is not in Igraph. It's useless for anything more serious then a dry stick. I go for best solution nr 1 and I think [this here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13522759/1863061) will do it.