# K longest paths in a DAG

Tags: python, algorithm, shortest-path, longest-path, viterbi

I want to find K longest paths in a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG). I have read few articles about it but I couldn't find any actual code that has implemented it. Can somebody help me with a python or pseudo code?

Here is one interesting algorithm explanation:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3009499/

Comment: It's unlikely to be the fastest, but very simple to implement: Use [Floyd-Washall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) for all pairs shortest paths, negating all the edge weights. Then look for the most negative path lengths in the result.

Comment: Sina, the paper seems like about finding most probable HMM paths, rather than longest ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://baoilleach.blogspot.ca/2013/11/the-shortest-route-to-longest-path.html

Also you can negate weights and apply some existing package for k shortest paths in weighted graph, granted negative weights are supported.

If negatives are not supported you can resort to graph weight rewriting as in Johnson algorithm (see wikipedia or/and https://www.researchgate.net/publication/275645125_Weighted_graph_algorithms_with_Python and then apply k shortest paths, say Dijkstra's  [Python Dijkstra k shortest paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519030/python-dijkstra-k-shortest-paths)

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm does not work for negative edge weights.

Comment: explained how rewrite weights for Dijkstra's algo